# Unique rows Indexeddb indexed array

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I have a store in IndexedDB where the Key path is for property Id and I also have an indexed array called *IndexedWords*

```
[{ Id: 1, IndexedWords: ['Foo', 'bar'] }, { Id: 2, IndexedWords: [] } }
```

I am trying to find all empty rows in the store and this by finding Id of all with value in *IndexedWords* + all Id of the store and intersecting those arrays. The idea works but the problem is that I am receiving the Ids for the *IndexedWords* x number of times where x matches the number of entries in *IndexedWords* and when I have 5000 rows and each row have 100+ words, the array is getting large and harder to work with. Is there any way of returning only distinct Ids from IndexedDB in the query? Current code below

```
var trans = db.transaction(storeName, IDBTransaction.READ_ONLY);
var index = trans.objectStore(storeName).index("IndexedWords");
var getAllRequest = index.getAllKeys();
getAllRequest.onsuccess = function (evt) {
    items = evt.target.result;
}
```

Comment: Try it with an ordinary 'array' instead of 'indexeddb'.  I expect that numeric keys work better with arrays; string keys work better with 'indexeddb'.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. Are you trying to get all of the Ids that contain each IndexedWord?  i.e., [{'Foo': [1], 'Bar': [1]}]? If you could provide a minimum working example it would really help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you could try creating a multiple entry index on `IndexedWords` and then iterating over the unique keys of the index.

Comment: Much shorter and better explanation, yes

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps, without the overhead of the IndexedDB API, since I was not able to get your IndexedDB sample code working.

Iterate over the words and create a new object containing a word as the key, with an array of Ids as the value if the word is in the IndexedWords for the item.

Create an empty object and some sample data

```
let index = [{ Id: 1, IndexedWords: ['Foo', 'bar'] }, { Id: 2, IndexedWords: ['blue', 'cat', 'mouse'] }, {Id: 242, IndexedWords: ['salmon', 'blue', 'bar']} ];
let wordz = {};
```

Create a flat array of all the unique words from the sample data, and remove the duplicates from the array of all of the words to get a list of distinct words.

```
let allWords = index.map((z) => (z.IndexedWords)).flat()
allWords = [...new Set(allWords)]
```

Iterate over each unique word and create a new object with the word as the key, with an array of Ids as the value

```
allWords.forEach( (word) => {
    // create an empty array for the new wordz[word]
    wordz[word] = []

    // push the item Id onto wordz[word] //
    index.forEach((item) => {
        if(item.IndexedWords.indexOf(word)>=0) {
            wordz[word].push(item.Id);
            }
    })
})



console.log(wordz)

Foo: [1]
bar: (2) [1, 242]
blue: (2) [2, 242]
cat: [2]
mouse: [2]
salmon: [242]
```